# Modify the URL of a new Request Object in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, request, fetch-api

I'm just playing around the with `Fetch` API and I came across something that I can't seem to find the answer to. If I create a new request object like so:

```
let request = new Request('http://www.foo.com', {
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: new Headers({
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })
});
```

If I then try and modify the URL (append a query string to it) I receive an error in the browser (`Cannot assign to read only property`). I know that usually with an object, you can set `writable` to 'True' but does this work the same for a request object?

The reason that I ask is that I am trying to append a querystring to the end of the URL. These `options` are in another object, which I've got the values of and concatenated into a string so that it's something like:

`number=1&id=130&foo=bar` etc.

Am I trying to over engineer what I am doing here?

Comment: When you say, “modify the URL (append a query string to it)”, what does your code look like that you’re trying to do that with? And if you omit `mode: 'no-cors'`, are you able to modify the URL then? And why are you using `mode: 'no-cors'`? Using that tells the browser not to allow your JavaScript code to access the response at all. So even if the request get made successfully, that `mode: 'no-cors'` is going to prevent you from being able to do anything with the response.

Comment: You can put the query string on the url before you create the Request object.

Comment: Sorry I set the mode to `no-cors` because I was developing locally. I'm just trying to hit a URL setup in API Gateway. I'll update with the code that you've requested.

Comment: @sideshowbarker if I remove the `no-cors` I get the following error, `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` as `localhost` can't access the URL

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, thought I was being a bit thick, you're spot on. I didn't think to simply edit the URL first and then when creating a new request object just add the variable housing the modified URL instead of a URL!

Comment: OK so the thing is, if the site isn’t sending the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, the browser’s gonna block all access to the response from your JavaScript code anyway. You’ll be able to see the response in devtools but your browser won’t expose it to your code unless the response has Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Setting `mode: 'no-cors'` does not get you around that restriction. All that `mode: 'no-cors'` does is, it tells the browser not to even bother to check for the Access-Control-Allow-Origin but to instead just block your code from getting to the response regardless

Comment: @sideshowbarker Ah ok, understood. So really, that's not something that I can control on my end is it. As I said it's just experimental stuff for now but good to know. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Yeah it’s not something you can control on your own end. You’d either need to set up a proxy or else send your request through an open proxy like https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.foo.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify the url of a request object in fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62118529/how-to-modify-the-url-of-a-request-object-in-fetch-api)

Answer (score 29):

You can copy all the properties from the old request into a new one with a new url like so:

```js
const init = { 
  method: 'GET',
  mode: 'no-cors',
  headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })
};
const oldRequest = new Request("https://old-url.com", init);
const newRequest = new Request("https://new-url.com", oldRequest);

console.log(newRequest.mode === oldRequest.mode); // true
console.log(newRequest.headers.get('Content-Type') === oldRequest.headers.get('Content-Type')); // true
console.log(newRequest.method === oldRequest.method); // true
```

Comment: This is a much better response, and ought to be the selected response.

Comment: Here are the instance properties of `Request`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request#instance_properties - (14) ['body', 'bodyused', 'cache', 'credentials', 'destination', 'headers', 'integrity', 'method', 'mode', 'redirect', 'referrer', 'referrerpolicy', 'signal', 'url']

Comment: Here are the `options` that can be passed in as the second param: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request#options (13) ['body', 'cache', 'credentials', 'headers', 'integrity', 'keepalive', 'method', 'mode', 'priority', 'redirect', 'referrer', 'referrerpolicy', 'signal']

Comment: `bodyUsed` probably doesn't matter in this case. `destination` seems to be automatically set somehow, because it's not an accepted option `keepalive` probably does. `priority` isn't copied over. Does `signal` work when copied over? There's also a new instance property not mentioned in MDN: `isHistoryNavigation`

Comment: `new Request(location.href)` seems to print out the same properties as `new Request(location.href, new Request(location.href))`. So that's good. Those properties are: `body,bodyUsed,cache,credentials,destination,headers,integrity,isHistoryNavigation,keepalive,method,mode,redirect,referrer,referrerPolicy,signal,url`. Only `headers` and `signal` are instances, rest are primitives (boolean, string, etc).

Comment: Typescript's `RequestInit` object (i.e. options that can be passed as second parameter to `new Request`) are: `body,cache,credentials,headers,integrity,keepalive,method,mode,redirect,referrer,referrerPolicy,signal,window`

Comment: I would say my only concern would be around `signal`. `keepalive` actually does appear in instance properties, in chrome at least, so MDN may be outdated there.

Comment: Somehow there is a `duplex` property that is getting forwarded in my case (monkey-patching node v20's `fetch` as used in `SolidStart v0.3.2`). Causing this error in chrome: "Failed to construct 'Request': The `duplex` member must be specified for a request with a streaming body"

Comment: I also got a TS type error when reading the `window` property off an existing Request instance. I'm not sure how to discover other request options besides looking at typescript type defs.

Comment: `duplex` in my case was undefined (and the property appears to also be missing, but don't quote me on that). I can solve this error by passing `{ ...currentRequest }` instead of `currentRequest`. Even `currentRequest.clone()` has the same error wrt `duplex`.

Comment: this thread has some good info: https://github.com/whatwg/fetch/issues/1486#issuecomment-1250073926

Comment: I wasn't quite satisfied with any of my approaches, and ended up just using patch-package to change the url passed to the "original" `new Request`. Here is some of my code which I'm not using, but others could pickup where I left off: https://gist.github.com/devinrhode2/c0545b8715072cb7a7908b125cb4e65c

Answer (score 7):

`Request` object is immutable by design, don't try to change it.

I wish `clone()` instance method accepted options to be able to to tweak the cloned object, but it doesn't. So I came up with this function:

```
function appendQuery(urlOrReq, queryString) {
    // make sure we deal with a Request object even if we got a URL string
  const req = urlOrReq instanceof Request ? urlOrReq : new Request(urlOrReq);

  const {
    cache, credentials, headers, integrity, method,
    mode, redirect, referrer, referrerPolicy, url, body
  } = req;

  // Don't add query string if there's none
  const urlWithQuery = url + (!queryString ? '' : '?' + queryString);

  return new Request(urlWithQuery, {
    cache, credentials, headers, integrity, method,
    mode, redirect, referrer, referrerPolicy, body
  })
}
```

Here's the same in TypeScript (only the first line is different):

```
function appendQuery(urlOrReq: RequestInfo, queryString?: string): Request {
    // make sure we deal with a Request object even if we got a URL string
  const req = urlOrReq instanceof Request ? urlOrReq : new Request(urlOrReq);

  const {
    cache, credentials, headers, integrity, method,
    mode, redirect, referrer, referrerPolicy, url, body
  } = req;

  // Don't add query string if there's none
  const urlWithQuery = url + (!queryString ? '' : '?' + queryString);

  return new Request(urlWithQuery, {
    cache, credentials, headers, integrity, method,
    mode, redirect, referrer, referrerPolicy, body
  })
}
```

Here's how it works:

```
const req = new Request('https://google.com')
appendQuery(req, 'foo=42')
// => Request {method: "GET", url: "https://google.com?foo=42", headers: Headers, destination: "", referrer: "about:client", …}
```

Comment: `Request object is immutable by design`

it is immutable, but you can change headers :)) I think it will be more convenient to make url instance of URL, so you can easily modify searchParams

Comment: This approach won't work for requests which have `body`, as it needs to be copied as a stream.